# Problems with Nexus hosted pypi repos after updating from 3.46 to 3.47

Tags: pypi, nexus3

Hello today I updated my NEXUS OSS repo manager from 3.46 to 3.47.

In the system status page I am seeing the error message:

`X transactions with excessive retries in last hour`
with the counter X steadily mounting.

Users are unable to download pip packages from the repository.

The  error is:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nexus.mercator-ocean.fr', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /repository/pypi-all/simple/zarr/
```

If it works, it works for one package and then the error above happens.

Any ideas ?

OS is Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21)